# How can I nicely group fields in scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to parse the WPS protocol.
I would like to group many fields in one field in a Wireshark fashion.
For example, in Wireshark, Data Element Type, Data Element Lenght and Version are grouped under a field called Version.

In this example, Version is the only field I care about.
In Scapy I would like to show something like this:

```
>>>packet[WPS]
< WPS version=[Data Element Type=0x104a, Data Element Length=1,version=0x10] |>
```

and if I do:

```
>>>packet[WPS].version
0x10
```

Right now, I have the following code:

```
wps_message_types = {   4:"M1",
                    5:"M2",
                    7:"M3",
                    8:"M4",
                    9:"M5",
                    10:"M6",
                    11:"M7",
                    12:"M8",
                    15:"WSC_Done" }
class WPS(Packet): # eap type 253 vendor id 0x372a
    name = "Wi-Fi Protected Setup"
    fields_desc = [ ByteField("opcode", 1),
                    FlagsField("flags", 0, 8, ['more_flags', 'length']),
                    ShortField("Data_Element_type(version)", 0),
                    ShortField("Data_Element_lenght", 0),
                    ByteField("Version", 0),
                    ShortField("Data_Element_type:(Message type)", 0),
                    ShortField("Data_Element_length", 0),
                    ByteEnumField("Message_type", 0, wps_message_types),
                    StrField("data","")
        ]
    def getType(self):
        return wps_message_types[self.Message_type]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot of the Wireshark display you want?